# Bad directive in format '%' datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

When i try to change format of str to date time , i face ValueError,

this may simple problem but cant find solution on google or stackoverflow too , i found some solution about 'z' is bad directive in format but not '%' one

```
current_session.date = datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%B-%d% %H:%M')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rambod/PycharmProjects/mailWatcher/smtpINWatcher.py", line 92, in <module>
    current_session.date = datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%B-%d% %H:%M')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 351, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format)) from None
ValueError: '%' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%B-%d% %H:%M'
```

Comment: You have an extra % after 'd'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
current_session.date = datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%B-%d %H:%M')
```

(Note the removal of the extra `%` after `d`.)

**EDIT:**
The above will still be incorrect because `%B` is the full month name, so you should instead try:

```
current_session.date = datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: try to execute the code yourself, this pattern is wrong anyway:)

Answer (score 3):

`%B` is for Month as locale’s full name. like

> January, February, …, December (en_US);
>       Januar, Februar, …, Dezember (de_DE)

Your example

```
In [25]: date = datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')                                                                                                                       

In [26]: date                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[26]: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 16, 0, 2)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `%` sign after `%d`, that's the reason. However, the pattern is still wrong for the string you're trying to parse - `%B` stands for full month name, not number. I suppose `%m` is what you need:

```
datetime.strptime('2019-06-16 00:02', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

[Here's](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) a good description on how `strftime` works. Or check [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more detailed explanation.